# Different titles for static, posts, and every xy page

Tags: title, conditional-content

I have:

- a static front page "Home"
- a page  with all my posts "My posts"
- all the other post/pages from the blog "Post x / Page y"

and each one of them should display its title in the header. I'm almost there, this is my code in header.php

```
<?php if( is_home() && get_option('page_for_posts') ) : ?>
    <h1><?php echo apply_filters('the_title',get_page( get_option('page_for_posts') )->post_title); ?> (posts page - "My posts")</h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a> (static front page "Home")</h1>

<?php else : ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a> (all the other pages - "Any page/post")</h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

My problem is that when I'm on "My posts" it shows both the "My posts" title and the title of the latest post. I need only the former. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() && !is_home() ) :?> 
    <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
<?php elseif ( is_home() && get_option('page_for_posts') ): ?>
    <h1><?php echo apply_filters('the_title',get_page( get_option('page_for_posts') )->post_title); ?></h1>
 <?php else : ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with a little help from [here](http://kuttler.eu/post/different-titles-for-blog-and-front-page/).